# DX11 Alpha Blend Object Draw To Render Target

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, directx-11, alphablending

My problem is:

i can't draw an Alpha Blend object into render target with it's blend rightly,

i have a few experience on dx9 but not in dx11 so don't know what i miss in dx11.

please follow images...

Any flag must be set in dx 11 when create render target ? or add any code for blend or..
i don't know what i miss.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`ID3D11Device::CreateBlendState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For standard alpha blending with preserved alpha, use the following parameters:

```
AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;
BlendEnable[0] = TRUE;
SrcBlend[0] = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
DestBlend[0] = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
BlendOp[0] = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
SrcBlendAlpha[0] = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
DestBlendAlpha[0] = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
BlendOpAlpha[0] = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
RenderTargetWriteMask[0] = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
```

And don't forget to call `ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetBlendState`.